# How to assign initial_token value using puppet in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, puppet, datastax-enterprise, datastax, puppetlabs-apache

I want to assign the `initial_token` value in `cassandra.yaml` file using puppet automation. Can any one please tell me how to do it.

I cannot use virtual nodes because vnodes are not supported for hadoop and solr nodes.

Example: If I had an array of:

`['-9223372036854775808', '-3074457345618258603', '3074457345618258602']`

I need to assign each value to each node.

Comment: Is this what http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506693/assigning-dynamic-values-to-each-node-in-puppet is all about?

Comment: Yes.It is the same thing am trying to achieve.

Comment: OK. I'd recommend removing the other question then. As for the matter at hand, do I understand correctly that each node should use **one** of the values? Is there a given order to the nodes?

Comment: I will remove the other one. Yes each node should use one of the values and order does not matter for the first time but when we keep adding the nodes then the order matters. So it will be better if we control the order. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store that array in a variable in the manifest.

**EDIT:** if using Cassandra **=< 1.2** most Puppet Cassandra modules should have a parameter to set this option. So you could then pass a value from the array into there.
For example: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/gini/cassandra

If you're not using a module to set up Cassandra already with this as a parameter, you could create a template of the Cassandra.yaml and just use ERB to input a value from that array into the template.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html

**EDIT:**

Now I am back at a PC I can think a bit more. The instant solution I can think of is to define the tokens in a hash of either node IP address or node hostname => token - `'127.0.0.1' => '-9223372036854775808'`. This could be created in the manifest or you can do it via Hiera. If in Hiera, you'll need to extract it into a variable anyway in the manifest.

Then in the template you should be able to reference it with `<%= variableName[@::ipaddress_eth0] %>` for example.

Comment: I think the gini project is not using inital_tokens. https://github.com/gini/puppet-cassandra/issues/7. I am using the template for cassandra.yaml file but if I pass the array of tokens through a variable it assigns all the values to the inital_token.

Comment: In the template you can reference a specific value of the array with: <%= arrayname[0] %> to output the first value

Comment: Then how to maintain different index numbers for different nodes. As you said how can I set the variable name for node 1 with <%= arrayname[0] %> and node 2 with <%= arrayname[1] %>. I can assign only once in template/cassandra.yaml.erb file right?

Comment: Ah yes, I have had a quick think and updated my answer with my initial thoughts on a solution